# Can't register an app with Google Drive in the APIs Console

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to register an app in the APIs Console to test the Google Drive SDK.  However I can't find anywhere in the APIs console (after having the Drive SDK enabled) where I can fill in additional information as instructed on the [Register an App](https://developers.google.com/drive/register) page.

Where exactly is the "API Projects menu"?  I only see on the left of the screen the following options:

- Overview
- Services
- Team
- API Access
- Reports
- Quotas

None of these options allow me to enter additional information for the Drive SDK.

Comment: Never mind.  I just realized that I had enabled only the Drive API but not the Drive SDK.  Enabling both resolved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to enable the Drive SDK and Drive API from the "Services" pane of the [APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console).